# Google Drive API v3 - error sending files in chunks

Tags: delphi, google-drive-api, pascal

I was making an application to send backup files to the Drive, however, when I try to send the files in chunks, I am getting a 400 error in the first request.

```
procedure TMainForm.btnTesteClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  cURL = 'URL from requset';
  cFilePath = 'path of File';
var
  zIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  zParams: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  zIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  zMemFile: TFileStream;
begin
  zIdHTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create();
  zParams:=  TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create();
  zIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
  try
    zIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    zIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    zIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode:= [];
    zIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth:=0;
    zIdHTTP.IOHandler:= zIOHandler;
    zIdHTTP.HandleRedirects:= True;

    try
      zMemFile:= TFileStream.Create(cFilePath, fmOpenReadWrite);

      zIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Length', '8388608');
      zIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Range', 'bytes 0-8388607/178498359');

      zParams.AddFormField('data', 'application/octet-stream', '', zMemFile);
      ShowMessage(zIdHTTP.Put(cURL, zParams));
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do ShowMessage(IntToStr(zIdHTTP.ResponseCode));
      on E:Exception do ShowMessage('Error: Code: '+IntToStr(zIdHTTP.ResponseCode)+' - Message: '+E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(zMemFile);
    FreeAndNil(zIdHTTP);
end;
end;
```

the error message that appears is as follows: "Connection reset by peer"

The request is being made with the TIDHTTP component, but I also tested it with other components and the error continues to happen.

Does anyone know how to fix this error ?

I've tried it with other components like REST, and I've also tested it with insomnia.

Comment: I'm sure you tried [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/products/insomnia) and not [insomnia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insomnia#Noun). Also [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) a concept/interface, not a component. In case you mean with "_the Drive_" [OneDrive then you have to use the HTTP `PUT` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online).

Comment: For larger files you really should use a resumable upload. Basically: "Send the initial request and retrieve the resumable session URI. Upload the data and monitor upload state. (optional) If the upload is disturbed, resume the upload."  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#resumable

Comment: Hi, there,
You might use GitIt package embedded with Delphi, there are some packages providing Google Drive feature.

If you want to create these feature, you should use TRestClient and TRectRequest, both of the components support SSL natively.

I love Indy, and I created DNS server component for Indy, but Indy with SSL on multiple platforms is not easy to deploy.